# Интеграция Unity с 1с

Tags: unity3d, 1с

Довольно странный и необычный вопрос. Есть ли возможность интеграции Unity 3D с 1С Бухгалтерия или другой конфигурацией. Выглядеть должно примерно так: Unity связан с 1С и Unity подгружает из 1С количество объектов (допустим стулья), также в Unity реализован что-то типо редактора и мы видим количество стульев и при установки он списывается из 1С и соответственно в Unity мы это видим. Возможно это что-то на грани фантастики, но может кто-то реализовывал такое?

Comment: Вы немного не в ту сторону смотрите. 1. Алгоритмы взаимодействия между сущностями в Unity реализуются с помощью C#. Таким образом Ваш вопрос уже меняется с "Unity + 1C" на "C# + 1C". 2. Если в качестве зранилища данных в 1С используется MS SQL Server, то Ваш вопрос опять трансформируется в "C# + MS SQL Server". А дальше на уровне Unity реализовать CRUD-приложение - крайне несложная задача. :-)

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку )

Comment: Так же можете не через саму СУБД, а прям с 1С данными обмениваться.

Comment: А как это реализуется? Через какие-то API 1с ?

Comment: Общая схема может быть такой: из 1С весь функционал доступен через COM объект; COM компонента уже может использовать функционал unity. В этом случае взаимодействие инициируется из 1С; Этот же механизм можно реализовать и в обратном направлении: из unity-приложения создается COM объект 1С, Через который можно получить/записать данные;

Comment: Смотря чем опять же. Можно использовать COM объект, можно HTTP запросы, можно (если 1С использует клиент-серверную архитектуру) сразу ломиться в СУБД. Собсна что удобней, то и выбирайте)
Извиняюсь за такой вопрос, но мне дико интересно для чего такая задача?) Чем так обусловлена?